# Where does the console output go in Jenkins for .NET applications?

Tags: .net, mstest, jenkins

I am running some unit tests using MSTest and some of them print output to the console via Console.Write(). The output is not showing up in the usual Jenkins job log.

Where does the output show up (if anywhere) OR and even better solution would be if there a way to print output that Jenkins will capture in its job log?

Comment: Are you capturing or redirecting the output to the log file?

Comment: Can you see the log from the jenkins job console?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you start your MSTest, if you are using any scripting language other than windows batch file, that may be the cause. Basically you will need to provide more information.